# Should I install SELinux to make my Ubuntu Web server more secure?

Tags: security, webserver, selinux

[This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux) on using SELinux with Ubuntu informs of the following:

> The Ubuntu-specific "selinux" and "selinux-policy-ubuntu" packages
>   documented here have not received much attention since Karmic, and
>   appear to be effectively broken in Precise.

So does it make sense to even consider installing SELinux with the purpose of making a general-purpose Web server running on Ubuntu 12.04 more secure? What are the potential problems that SELinux can bring into an Ubuntu Web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the case of a web server, SELinux is probably overkill. Talking with the "ubuntu-hardened" folks the focus seems to be on [Apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor). I think this is fine and you can further lock down the Apparmor Apache profile if you want. Assuming your running Apache and SSH. I would run them both in their own [chrooted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) environments.